# Parse an integer with 9 digits into an array of colors

Tags: java

I have an array of nine digit numbers with a range of 0 - 999,999,999.  I want to be able to parse them into an array of [Colors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)).  I then want to be able to convert the array of colors back to the array of numbers.

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
Color[] colors = encode(intEnter);//intEnter is any integer which is 8 or 9 characters long.
int decode = decode(colors);//returns intEnter
```

I would like to do new Color(999, 999, 999), but it only supports up to 255.

How can I create an array of Colors to encode larger numbers than rgb supports and then decode it back?

Comment: I'm confused. I see no reason in adding `0` in front of `20`. Also, for invalid numbers such as `999_999_999`, we can't prevent such numbers since we don't know where they're even coming from (What's the `.exe`? Why are you grabbing numbers from it how you are?). Why do these 3 value (RGB) need to be combined into one? This is a very confusing situation. I'd ask you to explain further, but your post is pretty long as it is, so I suggest reformatting your question. Make it look a little more appealing

Comment: @VinceEmigh I am adding a 0 in front of the 20 because I need to convert the int back to three bytes later.  I have the exe because I am intending to convert the exe to a png file with it encrypted.  I need the numbers to be 3-3-3 so I can convert it back to bytes after I am done.  I want to convert ints with 9 digits to an array of colors I can add to a picture and later retrieve in the decryption process.  I think I have found a way to solve my own problem, so I may be posting an answer to my question if it works.

Comment: You can easily create a `Color` with 3 `int` values simply by using the constructor `Color(int, int, int)`. I understand why you have the `0` prefixes now, I didn't realize you were concating the strings before parsing, because `parseInt("09")` would omit the `0`, which is why I was confused at first. But I'm still not understanding the `999_999_999`, seeing how that's something generated from your `.exe`, so what do you want to do when you get a number that large? You can't prevent it, since you can't "prevent" what your `.exe` contains. Trying my best to understand your problem.

Comment: @VinceEmigh The 999999999 is the max value for an int which is 9 digits long.  I need a range from 0 - 999999999 to be parsed to a Color.  This won't work by doing rgb because they have a max of 255 and a min of 0 and you can't enter 999.

Comment: I understand that... But we can't prevent the `.exe` from generating a number like `999_999_999` using your system. So what do you want to happen when a `999_999_999` appears? I understand the basics, you just aren't being specific enough. If your system were to generate a `999_999_999`, what should happen?

Comment: @VinceEmigh If it were to generate 999_999_999, it will somehow be converted to an array of unique colors which I can convert back to 999_999_999.  Did you see the code I edited to the end of my post?  My question is about what to do with numbers like these to parse them to an array of Colors.

Comment: Actually, your title suggests your question is about parsing a 9 digit integer into a `Color`. Your bolded question suggests it's about generating an integer that's 9 digits long, which stores info for 3 3-digit numbers. Now you're saying it's about creating a safe-guard for invalid numbers (*which you haven't shown an attempt for*). Like I said before, this is a **very** confusing and misleading question, and you should reformat it. Not to mention, each of these questions should be separated into different posts (1 question per post) to avoid being closed as "too broad".

Comment: Reformat your question and I'll post an answer that fits.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I reformatted it.

Comment: Still 2 questions in 1, and you kinda removed your attempt, but I'll leave it up to the community to decide. What about using your `byte[]` from before, taking each byte and converting it to an unsigned byte (0-255), then forming colors using the unsigned bytes in pairs of 3, filling in the missing color values for the last color with `0` if needed. Would that work for you? That would prevent the max 9 digit situation. There are many different ways to do this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I would like to do that, but I am going to create an encryption method and it is going to be larger than an unsigned byte.  I have devised an answer which works, but it is a bit sloppy.  I am going to be posting it in a moment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*the encryption method is going to be larger than an unsigned byte*". Mind explaining that? You could easily convert an array of unsigned bytes to an array of `Color`. Unsigned bytes in Java are held in `short[]` or `int[]`, since `255` is too big for a `byte`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I was thinking of using a key and encrypt the integers using the key so if someone got a hold of the image generated using the colors, it will be useless without the key.  Also I figured it out, and now it encodes the file into and array of color and back to the file perfectly.

Comment: You could still encrypt the bytes. If you'd like, I'll post the unsigned bytes to `Color` solution, in case you were interested in checking it out

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than combining 3 bytes to form a 9 digit integer, create a color using the 3 bytes. You have to unsign them first, though, to offset the range to `0` to `255` rather than `-128` to `127`.

Consider you have a `byte[]` of size `100_000` full of bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[100_000];

new Random().nextBytes(bytes); //fills array with bytes; simulates bytes from stream
```

An unsigned byte value cannot fit in a `byte`, so we must use a `short[]` or `int[]`. To convert a signed byte to an unsigned byte, we use the bitewise `&` against `255` (more commonly seen as `0xff`):

```
int[] unsign(byte[] bytes) {
    int[] unsignedBytes = new int[bytes.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < unsignedBytes.length; i++) {
        unsignedBytes[i] = bytes[i] & 0xff;
    }

    return unsignedBytes;
}
```

To group these into 3s, we need to first ensure the amount of bytes we have is divisble by 3. For example, if we have an array of `[101, 74, 88, 21]`, we could either remove the `21` to create a color, or add 2 `0`s to create 2 colors. **The first choice results in lost data**, so we will go with the second option:

```
int[] sizeArray(int[] unsignedBytes) {
    int length = unsignedBytes.length;
    int bytesPerColor = 3;
    int remainder = length % bytesPerColor;
    int bytesNeeded = bytesPerColor - remainder;

    int numOfBytes = remainder > 0 ? length + bytesNeeded : length;
    int[] sizedArray = new int[numOfBytes];
    System.arrayCopy(unsignedBytes, 0, sizedArray, length);

    return sizedArray;
}
```

Now for the encoding. For every 3 bytes, we generate a color:

```
Color[] encode(int[] unsignedBytes) {
    Color[] colors = new Color[unsignedBytes.length / 3];

    for(int i = 0, position = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        int r = unsignedBytes[position++];
        int g = unsignedBytes[position++];
        int b = unsignedBytes[position++];

        colors[i] = new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    return colors;
}
```

To decode, simply grab the RGB values from each color:

```
int[] decode(Color[] colors) {
    int[] unsignedBytes = new int[colors.length * 3];

    int position = 0;
    for(Color color : colors) {
        unsignedBytes[position++] = color.getRed();
        unsignedBytes[position++] = color.getGreen();
        unsignedBytes[position++] = color.getBlue();
    }

    return unsignedBytes;
}
```

To sign the bytes, simply cast them back to bytes:

```
byte[] sign(int[] unsignedBytes) {
    byte[] signedBytes = new byte[unsignedBytes.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < signedBytes.length; i++) {
        signedBytes[i] = (byte) unsignedBytes[i];
    }

    return signedBytes;
}
```

---

You could have an `Encoder` and a `Decoder` class, which takes care of the signing and unsigning for you if needed:

```
class Encoder {
    public Color[] encode(byte[] signedBytes) {
        return encode(unsign(signedBytes));
    }

    public Color[] encode(int[] unsignedBytes) {
        //...
    }

    private int[] unsign(byte[] signesBytes) {
        //...
    }
}

class Decoder {
    public byte[] decode(Color[] colors) {
        //receive unsigned bytes from colors

        return sign(unsignedBytes);
    }

    private byte[] sign(int[] unsignedBytes) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Wrote this from my phone, so let me know if there are any problems

Comment: Wow very good to be written from a phone.  This will work for what I want, I will just have to change the way  I planned to do with the bytes.  Thank you.

Comment: @Forseth11 Something I noticed while testing: applications will generate a lot of bytes, which means quite a few colors (which means quite a bit of memory and processing time). If using this, I suggest using a fork-and-join system when creating the colors. I'm writing up a system that combines a bunch of bytes into a single int (rather than 3 bytes per int (9 digit int), it may be 10k bytes per color, up to, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (accounting for alpha as well), generating less colors. Use the 3 bytes per color for smaller apps. Ill edit in an alternative for larger apps and notify you

Comment: I don't know what a fork and join system is.  Since there are only 16,777,216 possible rgb colors I am not sure you can put in more than three bytes because between 4 bytes there are 4,228,250,625 possible combinations.  I was going to have it read a file into a byte array and split it up so when it does save it to an image it will be a max of 3000 x 3000 pixels.  It would save multiple images into a zipped folder.  I am intending for this to be able to save my entire computer to a massive zip and have it encrypted in images.

Comment: @Forseth11 4.2 billion colors with RGBA. Fork/Join is a *divide and conquer* system. If we had 1002 bytes, we could form 344 colors. Instead of creating them one at a time, you would divide the `byte[]` and have 2 threads each creating 167 colors. You could divide further, have 4 threads creating colors, ect. Java has a Fork/Join implementation which you can [learn about on their site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). If you have 100m bytes, thats 33m colors. Creating them 1 at a time could take a while, so its best to split the work across threads

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to answer my own question, but it is a bit sloppy.  Basically I can subtract 16777215 from the number and create a color with its rgb set as 16777215.  It will do this until one number is left over and it will create a color with the remaining number.  For each number in the array it create a color array with the first color being the the value of how many colors in the array make up the specific number.

Here is my code:

```
Color[] colors = encode(999999999);
        Color[] colors2 = encode(120658366);
        Color[] colors3 = encode(596820492);
        Color[] colors4 = encode(123098765);
        Color[] colorsFinal = new Color[colors.length + colors2.length + colors3.length + colors4.length];

        int nextIndex=0;
        for(Color c : colors){
            colorsFinal[nextIndex] = c;
            nextIndex++;
        }
        for(Color c : colors2){
            colorsFinal[nextIndex] = c;
            nextIndex++;
        }
        for(Color c : colors3){
            colorsFinal[nextIndex] = c;
            nextIndex++;
        }
        for(Color c : colors4){
            colorsFinal[nextIndex] = c;
            nextIndex++;
        }

        int nextKey = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < colorsFinal.length; i++){
            if(i == nextKey){
                int count = 1 + (colorsFinal[i].getRGB() + 16777216);
                System.out.println(decode(Arrays.copyOfRange(colorsFinal, i, i + count)));
                nextKey+=count;
                i = nextKey-1;
            }
        }
```

Encode:

```
public static Color[] encode(int number){
        int count = number / 16777215;
        if(number % 16777215 > 0){
            count++;
        }
        Color[] colors = new Color[count+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                colors[i] = new Color(count);
            }else{
                if(number > 16777215){
                    number = number - 16777215;
                    colors[i] = new Color(16777215);
                }else{
                    colors[i] = new Color(number);
                }
            }
        }
        return colors;
    }
```

Decode:

```
public static int decode(Color[] colors){
    if(colors.length > 1){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < colors.length; i++){
            total += (colors[i].getRGB() + 16777216);
        }
        return total;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
999999999
120658366
596820492
123098765
```

This works to encode a 9 digit number into an array of colors, but I am sure it can be improved.  In fact this works for any integer which is positive.